# Using jquery-tmpl on responseText

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, sharepoint-2013, jquery-templates

I'm currently trying to fill jquery-templates that I get by using an ajax get on another folder on the server. I wanted to fill the responseTexts i get via .tmpl({..}). Sadly that didn't work. Here's what i do.

```
var a = $.ajax({
   method: 'GET',
   url : 'TemplateUrl/template.html'
});
$.when(a).done(function(){
   $(a.responseText).tmpl({...});
});
```

The responseText is a very simple piece of html from a SharePoint Site looking like this

```
    "<div>
<td class="ms-formbody">
    <!--    FieldName="{{html FieldName}}"
            FieldInternalName = "{{html FieldName}}"
            FieldType = "SPFieldText" -->
    {{html Text}}
</td>
</div>"
```

When trying to fill the template i get this

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'Text': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.
```

Maybe you guys have an idea. Would be great. Thanks in advance and

Greetings Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer wasn't that hard and pretty logical once I had it. The template-engine needs the script-wrapper to work properly. So the html needs to look like this

```
<script type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div>
        <td class="ms-formbody">
            <!--    FieldName="{{html FieldName}}"
                    FieldInternalName = "{{html FieldName}}"
                    FieldType = "SPFieldText" -->
            {{html Text}}
        </td>
        </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it throws the error is because you are trying to invoke temp() as a function instead of instantiating it.

Try using new keyword in front of $(a.responseText).tmpl({...}).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Also tried the new $(a.responseText).tmpl({...});

Sadly it gives me the same result. Also first doing
var b = new $(a.responseText);
b.tmpl({...});
does not work